# Is it possible to run a C# script from another C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I know this is a stupid question but I just can't wrap my head around it. I have two scripts, *RandomWalk.cs* and *Chase.cs*.

They both work fine individually, however I'm trying to get it so that chase.cs calls randomwalk.cs through an if statement like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 20)
    {
        Attack();
    }
    else if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) > 20)
    {
        //Run RandomWalk.cs here
    }
}
```

Is this possible at all? Here is the whole script for reference:

```
public class Chase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float directionChangeInterval = 1;
    public float maxHeadingChange = 30;

    CharacterController controller;
    float heading;
    Vector3 targetRotation;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 20)
        {
            Attack();
        }
        else if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) > 20)
        {
            //Run RandomWalk.cs here            
        }
    }

    public void Attack() {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
        direction.y = 0;
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), .1f);

        if (direction.magnitude > 5) {
            this.transform.Translate(0, 0, .29f);
        }

        print("Attacking");
    }
}
```

Edit:
Here is the class I'm trying to run from the if statement:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class RandomWalk : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 5;
public float directionChangeInterval = 1;
public float maxHeadingChange = 30;
public Transform player;

CharacterController controller;
float heading;
Vector3 targetRotation;



    public void Awake()
{
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        // Set random initial rotation
        heading = Random.Range(0, 360);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, heading, 0);

        StartCoroutine(NewHeading());
    }

   public void Update()
{
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * directionChangeInterval);
        var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        controller.SimpleMove(forward * speed);

    }

    IEnumerator NewHeading()
{
        while (true)
        {
            NewHeadingRoutine();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(directionChangeInterval);
        }
    }

    void NewHeadingRoutine()
{
        var floor = Mathf.Clamp(heading - maxHeadingChange, 0, 360);
        var ceil = Mathf.Clamp(heading + maxHeadingChange, 0, 360);
        heading = Random.Range(floor, ceil);
        targetRotation = new Vector3(0, heading, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `randomwalk.cs` or call a function from `randomwalk.cs`?

Comment: Call randomwalk.cs

Comment: You can't call a class. You can call a function inside a class. Maybe you are looking for a way create new instance of `randomwalk`? I can't tell exactly what  you are doing but you should explain why you need to "call a class".

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've added the randomwalk class to show what I'm trying to run

Comment: You only added a the `RandomWalk` class. What do you mean by run? What do you expect to happen when you say run?

Comment: So I have two game objects, one with RandomWalk attached, the other with Chase attached. Currently, they both work fine, gameObject1 walks randomly (RamdomWalk.cs) around while gameObject2 does nothing until you get within a certain distance then moves(Chase.cs). I want to have it set where both gameObjects walk randomly and if they enter a certain distance from the player they will chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally wrapped my head around it, just needed to change the RandomWalk class to incorporate the Chase class

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class RandomWalk : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 5;
public float directionChangeInterval = 1;
public float maxHeadingChange = 30;
public Transform player;

CharacterController controller;
float heading;
Vector3 targetRotation;



    public void Awake() {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        // Set random initial rotation
        heading = Random.Range(0, 360);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, heading, 0);

        StartCoroutine(NewHeading());
    }

   public void Update() {
    if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 20)
    {
        Attack();
        print("Attacking");
    }
    else if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) > 20)
    {
        idleWalk();
        print("Idly walking");
    }

}

    IEnumerator NewHeading(){
        while (true)
        {
            NewHeadingRoutine();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(directionChangeInterval);
        }
    }

    void NewHeadingRoutine(){
        var floor = Mathf.Clamp(heading - maxHeadingChange, 0, 360);
        var ceil = Mathf.Clamp(heading + maxHeadingChange, 0, 360);
        heading = Random.Range(floor, ceil);
        targetRotation = new Vector3(0, heading, 0);
    }

public void Attack() {
    Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
    direction.y = 0;
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
                                        Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), .1f);

    if (direction.magnitude > 5) {
        this.transform.Translate(0, 0, .29f);
    }

    print("Attacking");
}

public void idleWalk() {
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * directionChangeInterval);
    var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    controller.SimpleMove(forward * speed);
}


}
```